Installing new motorcycle grips
I have a 2012 Ducati Monster 696. The grips were original, and completely needing replacement. I got these "motoGP" grips from Domino (whatever). The plastic throttle tube has a flared end toward the instrument cluster. From watching a few videos, I can't tell that all motorcycles have flared throttle ends like this. Is this a fitment issue, or do I really need to hoik the end of the grip over the throttle tube to ensure a good seal?
Never mind that the emblem is upside down, I couldn't work it on quickly enough before the lubricant lost give.


If the emblem is upside down, presumably that was intended for the left hand grip. Perhaps the left and right grips aren't quite the same, given that only the right side is the throttle, and the left is fixed.

@WeatherVane it's a good thought. But I can confirm the smaller inner diameter tube is on the clutch lever, in fact the emblem is printed twice on the grip, at horizontal flips from each other... Hard to describe and definitely "funky".
